# How to create setTimeout loop for yield put()

Tags: redux-saga

I have a saga watcher:

```
function* watchSetRefreshInterval() {
    yield takeLatest(SET_LOOP, setLoop);
}
```

and a `setLoop` saga

```
function* setLoop() {
        yield put({type: ANOTHER_WATCHER });
}
```

I want `yield put({type: ANOTHER_WATCHER });` to happen with interval

This does not work

```
setTimeout(function timeoutFn(){
        yield put({type: ANOTHER_WATCHER });
        setTimeout(timeoutFn, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

You cannot use `yield` in non-generator function, making `timeoutFn` a generator does not work as well.

How can I call `yield put` in an interval. I don't want to use

```
while(true) {
        yield delay(5000);
        yield put({type: ANOTHER_WATCHER });
}
```

I want to use `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a classic example of an `Event Channel`.

Check out the link below -

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html

Sample-

```
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga'

function countdown(secs) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
      const iv = setInterval(() => {
        secs -= 1
        if (secs > 0) {
          emitter(secs)
        } else {
          // this causes the channel to close
          emitter(END)
        }
      }, 1000);
      // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
      return () => {
        clearInterval(iv)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

In your saga file, create a delay function like:

```
const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
```

Then create the watcher like:

```
const fnWatcher = function* () {  
  yield call(delay, 2000);
  yield put({type: 'ACTION_SUCCESS'});
};

takeEvery("ACTION_NAME", fnWatcher);
```

Comment: Not working! the action ACTION_SUCCESS is executed without taking the delay call in consideration

Answer (score 0):

Using the delay helper is the right way to do this.

However, I guess you could do something like:

```
setTimeout(function timeoutFn(){
    sagaMiddleware.run(function*() {
        yield put({type: ANOTHER_WATCHER });
        setTimeout(timeoutFn, 5000);
    })
}, 5000);
```

Note that doing this is like using the `spawn` effect meaning the new generator is detached and won't be e.g. cancelled when the above generator is cancelled.

Comment: When attempting this, you get an error regarding sagaMiddleware. `Error: Before running a Saga, you must mount the Saga middleware on the Store using applyMiddleware`. What it's saying is, this is used to register each of your saga functions, which is often done in a parent context of your root saga. Since you are already in a saga registered via sagaMiddleware, and you are trying to register a new saga inside of that saga, you'd have to first pass down your sagaMiddleware from the parent context. This would be messy and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const { isFetching , statusCode } = this.props; 
 yield put(
      catalogueUpdateProductFormError({
        errorStatus: catalogueUpdateProductDetailsPayload.errorStatus,
        statusCode: 400,
      })
    );

    yield delay(4000);
    yield put(
      catalogueUpdateProductFormError({
        errorStatus: "",
        statusCode: -1,
      })
    );
```

// we want animation when api response 200 and 400

```
.toast {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

.fadeOut{
}
.fadeIn{
    opacity:1;
}

<div className={ statusCode === 400 ? 'toast fadeIn' : 'toast fadeOut'} >
    <SaveBehavior text={"productSavedError"} iconType="close" /> 
</div>
```